# How to create chunk of data programmatically and upload it to server

Tags: android, networking, bandwidth

As per my requirement I have to perform the upload test (similar to SpeedTest) for monitoring network bandwidth. First approach which I can think is “To place 1 file (let’s say 1Mb file) in mobile & upload this file to server & calculate the time for it”. But in this approach, there is a dependency of file. Is there any other way/API/Functionality by which I can create a chunk of data programmatically (at run time) & upload it to server?

Please correct me if I am going in wrong direction.
Thanks in advance.

-Shweta.

Answer (score 0):

will creating sockets and pump udp stream in uplink direction work?
make sure you synchronize times at both sides to a common NTP server.

Comment: Thanks Paul,
Could you please elaborate more. I am new in java/android platform. This may be useful for my requirement. How to do this udp stream in uplink direction?

-Shweta.